# How to read only letters from a file that includes letters and numbers?

Tags: c

I am working on a school project where my professor has given us the task to read a list of names and numbers from one file, and format them in a certain way and write them to another file. My professor told me to try and write two functions, one that reads the names from the input file and writes them to the output file, and another to read the numbers and write those to the output file. Currently, I am having a hard time figuring out how to read only the names from the input file. For context the input file is organized like this:

FirstName LastName 74 66 97 23 75

FirstName LastName 91 0 0 52
etc.

The output file must be organized like this: 
LastName, FirstName 74 66 97 23 75 *average of these numbers*

LastName, FirstName 91 0 0 52 *average of these numbers*

Currently, my function for reading the names reads only the names, however, every time there is a number, the function adds an unnecessary new line. Here is the code for my function:

```
char ch;
    ch = fgetc(fInput);
    while (ch) {
        fprintf(fOutput, "%c", ch);
        ch = fgetc(fInput);
        if (ch == '0' || ch == '1' || ch == '2' || ch == '3' || ch == '4' || ch == '5' || ch == '6' || ch == '7' || ch == '8' || ch == '9') {
            ch = '\n';
        }
        if (ch == EOF) {
            break;
        }
    }
```

fInput and fOutput are arguments for this function. My question is how can I get this function to read only the letters in the file.

Comment: Read a lot more documentation about standard [IO](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io) in C. Read also [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Take some time to read some [C programming tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/index.htm) and the [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) book. Be aware that files are often buffered.

Comment: `char ch;` ==> `int ch;` basically because `EOF` is an int and its conversion to char will match a valid character *(there's some caveats because of conversion from and to `unsigned char`)*.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should change the char ch to int.

Remove the ch ='\n' from

```
if (ch == '0' || ch == '1' || ch == '2' || ch == '3' || ch == '4' || ch == '5' || ch == '6' || ch == '7' || ch == '8' || ch == '9') {
            ch = '\n';
        }
```

Because at the next step of your while it prints first the last character and then reads the next one.

A better implementation of your idea would be:

```
int ch;
while((ch = fgetc(fInput)) != EOF){
    if(!isdigit(ch)){
        fprintf(fOutput, "%c, ch):
    }
}
```

add also include ctype.h to your libraries.